# Google play developer console in debug mode

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to test my application with achievement API - https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements

To set up all these achievements should I register google play developer console or there is another way of unlocking it in developer console (https://console.developers.google.com). Here i added all the API necessary to me, but can't find the page to set up achievement's details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to register to the developer console and then add your achievements, publish an alpha or beta version of your app, add tester accounts, setup the games service and only then can you test the achievements in your app.

Comment: Thx, i though if there is any other way to do this without deployment.